# Guys with a "boomstick"

Tags: story-identification

Here's a tough one, I'm looking for a novel in which one of the (two?) main characters grabs a "boomstick" as a weapon (possibly from the trunk of his car).

The boomstick is described as a device that fires a single shotgun shell and is used for sharks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerhead

It may have been "bang stick" not boom stick. I know the term boom stick is used

I'm wondering if it's David Wong's John Dies at the End (couldn't find the reference). Or a Christopher Moore book.

I know the phrase "boomstick" is used by Bruce Campbell in Army of Darkness. But I've never seen the film (came across a clip while looking for the book).

Any suggestions would be good.. even if you're not 100% I can cross-reference it with my reading list.

Comment: The only book I've come across where anyone uses a bangstick is Tom Clancy's Without Remorse, where the hero uses it to assassinate a drug dealer.

Comment: I know I have read this in a book as well.  I vaguely recall something in the Jurassic Park novel, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that you're thinking of *[Beat the Reaper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_the_Reaper)* by Josh Bazell?  There's not really any sci-fi to the story that I recall, but it was definitely dark comedy, sharks play a recurring theme in the story, and the main character was prone to violent. I'm not certain if there was a boomstick in the book(it's been a while since I read it), but one would definitely fit the story.

Answer (score 2):

As far as other sources, the term "boomstick" is such a common trope, it is difficult to determine where you may have seen it.

In my memory, the novel A Connecticut Yankee In King Arthur's Court involves a 19th century man sent back in time to King Arthur's court. He uses his modern knowledge to give Camelot new technology, debunk mystics and miracle workers, and become the most powerful man in the country.

Harry Turtledove (Guns of the South) and Poul Anderson (The Man Who Came Early) both have time travel stories where primitive people are exposed to advanced technologies (guns, in particular).

Comment: You watched JDATE, you didn't read it.  They very well could have omitted that from the movie like they omitted the great "Nice to MEAT you pun."

Comment: No, 'fraid none of those are ringing any bells. I believe it was a dark/horror comedy. And I've read both JDATE books twice.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about a novel but it sounds like you're talking about the movie Army of Darkness with Bruce Campbell. He and his car get transported to what looks like the middle ages. He is captured by the locals and is about to be killed when they are attacked by a witch. He grabs a shotgun from the trunk of his car and kills her. 
He tells the local it's his boomstick, warning the locals that when it goes boom they die.

Comment: The OP has stated that Army of Darkness is not the source.